# Как получить шрифт из файла .png?

Tags: android, шрифты, java

Подскажите пожалуйста как вытянуть шрифт из png файла? Или дайте ссылку. Хотел бы использовать свой шрифт в андроид приложении. Пример изображения со шрифтом:

[image: шрифт]

Comment: Создать его самостоятельно в редакторе шрифтов.

Comment: .png - это картинка =) способы есть, но тебе они не подойдут =)
ЗЫ твоя ссылка - сюда же

Comment: если нету стандартных решений, в чем я сомневаюсь, надо брать эту картинку и парсить попиксольно

Comment: Почему не подойдут? Мне подо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не вытаскивать шрифт, а сделать все картинками вырезанными из твоей картинки.

Comment: не подскажете кодом или ссылочкой как это лучше(правильней) сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Для определения шрифтов должны использовать векторные форматы, а png - растровый. Пользовательские шрифты подключаются в Android так. Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/font"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Это пользовательский шрифт."
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Код:

```
Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

tv.setTypeface(t);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз смотрел в книге как подключаются другие шрифты

Answer (score 2):

http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
Там довольно просто узнать, какой это шрифт как раз из картинки.
А потом - скачать в нормальной форме.